# I can't call an event, a KeyEvent, unless I minimize or resize my JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, keylistener

i have 3 classes inside a class. the main class will call one of the 3 classes, depending on the input of the user, if it is B, R or G. B for Blue class, r for red and g for green.

after i call a class, lets say Blue class, the blue will be added to the container and the class that calls this, a panel class will be removed from the container.

when i press the button "exit", the blue class will be removed and the panel class will be added to the container again.

my problem is, after i've done this scenario above, i can't call another class again, by pressing B, R or G. i must minimize or resize first my jframe to call a class. again

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class practice implements KeyListener{
JFrame frame = new JFrame("practice");
JLabel label = new JLabel("Press B, R, or G");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public class BLUE implements ActionListener{
    JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel();
    JButton exit = new JButton("exit");
    public BLUE(){
        bluePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        bluePanel.setFocusable(true);
        bluePanel.setVisible(true);
        bluePanel.requestFocus();
        bluePanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        bluePanel.add(exit);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        frame.remove(panel);
        frame.add(bluePanel);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource().equals(exit)){
            frame.remove(bluePanel);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }           
}


public class RED extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JPanel redPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton exit = new JButton("exit");
    public RED(){
        redPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        redPanel.setFocusable(true);
        redPanel.setVisible(true);
        redPanel.requestFocus();
        redPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        redPanel.add(exit);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        frame.remove(panel);
        frame.add(redPanel);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource().equals(exit)){
            frame.remove(redPanel);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }           
}

public class GREEN extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JPanel greenPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton exit = new JButton("exit");
    public GREEN(){
        greenPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        greenPanel.setFocusable(true);
        greenPanel.setVisible(true);
        greenPanel.requestFocus();
        greenPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
        greenPanel.add(exit);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        frame.remove(panel);
        frame.add(greenPanel);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource().equals(exit)){
            frame.remove(greenPanel);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }           

}

public practice(){  
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    initUI();
}

public void initUI(){
    frame.addKeyListener(this);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.add(panel);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){   
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_B){
        BLUE blue = new BLUE();
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_R){
        RED red = new RED();
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_G){
        GREEN green = new GREEN();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    practice p = new practice();
}
}
```

Comment: Use [Key Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of `KeyListener`.

Comment: Call `frame.setVisible` _after_ `frame.pack`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the focus is given to the panel after the call, and the JFrame then can't listen for input. You want to `requestFocus()` from the panel after the call is made.

Answer (score -1):

Your jframe (where you added the keyListener) lost focus as you request focus on the jpanels which do not have a keyListener. 
Use requestFocus() on the jframe after every change of jpanels, i cant test it myself atm though so not completely sure .

Comment: so im going to add 
frame.requestFocus(); inside the constructor of practice class?
am i right with what you're pertaining?

Comment: No actually after you call frame.repaint ()

Comment: Also from looking over the code it seems like the current jPanel is never removed before adding the new one. You might want to call frame.removeAll() before adding a new jPanel

Comment: Just frame.removeAll() stupid phone autocompleted, sorry

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% sure but I think your problem lies with what component is in focus.
Once you click the exit button the focus shifts to the exit button and even though it's removed later focus is never given back to the original frame.
At the end of your exit button code add:

```
frame.requstFocus();
```

Yup, checked and this works.

Comment: aw thanks. but still not working. if im right, i just added that inside my practice constructor

Comment: Did you add for every actionPerformed method?

Comment: its ok now. i added the code after the frame.repaint().